# Change WordPress image URLs via filter

Tags: images, filters, post-thumbnails

I'm planning to create a wordpress plugin that will offload uploaded images to external website and show them from there.

What I did so far:

1) Whenever a images gets uploaded, my custom functions will trigger and will upload the image including its thumbnails to the external site and store the urls to database.

No problems here. But how do I tell wordpress instead of showing default image url show my url? I am just looking for the correct filter/hooks. I'm googling for past 12 hours still hasn't found a proper answer.

What I want is, whenever requests a image the filter will change:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/dog-1200x1108.png
```

to

```
http://example.com/BAHIAPJGJSHSH.png
```

There are 2 plugins which does this: [DigitalOcean Spaces Sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/do-spaces-sync/) and [WP Offload Media](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/)

This 2 plugin does this although I'm trying to do it in a different image hoster. I've tried looking out there source code, but could not figure out.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?
How wordpress displays the image? and How to change the url via filter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will most likely want to use filters.  The main issue is that developers will need to make sure to use the correct functions like "the_post_thumbnail()" etc.
You can use wp_get_attachment_url
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url

I use this when doing local development, but want all my local images to load from the Production server as I don't have any images on my local machine.

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === '127.0.0.1') 
{
    // Replace src paths
    add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', function ($url) 
    {
        if(file_exists($url)) 
        {
            return $url;
        }
        return str_replace(WP_HOME, 'https://www.some-production-site.com', $url);
    });

    // Replace srcset paths
    add_filter('wp_calculate_image_srcset', function($sources)
    {
        foreach($sources as &$source) 
        {
            if(!file_exists($source['url'])) 
            {
                $source['url'] = str_replace(WP_HOME, 'https://www.some-production-site.com', $source['url']);
            }
        }
        return $sources;
    });
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you @ggedde. I made a few adjustments to check for the URL instead, with an early return and a MUPlugin - https://gist.github.com/mizner/8bed09419cf7ecc4182548a545c2e982

Answer (score 0):

The srcset can't work that way.
Here is a fix if ever needed.

```
add_filter('wp_calculate_image_srcset', function($sources)
{
    $sr = array();
    foreach($sources as $source) 
    {            
        $source['url'] = str_replace('http://localhost', 'https://www.some-production-site.com', $source['url']);           
        $sr[] =  $source;           
    }       
    return $sr;
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the srcset hook in the other answer? The file_exists URL bit looks suspicious to me, but can you explain what you mean by can't work that way?

Comment: The file_exists is there to only load external image if it's not found on localhost. The code that set's the source['url']  wasn't correct coz it's only setting the url for $source inside loop and not stored in $sources. That $source['url'] was never reflected in final $sources.

Comment: It is actually passed by reference( see the & in front) so it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I always use these two filters for my local WP environment with a remote database connection:

```
add_filter('pre_option_upload_path', function ($upload_path) {
    return '/wp-content/uploads/';
});

add_filter('pre_option_upload_url_path', function ($upload_url_path) {
    return '//example.com/wp-content/uploads/';
});
```

Change: "example.com" to your domain, and in your case, remote "/wp-content/uploads/".