# Clone WordPress for testing on localhost (with Fiddler)

Tags: htaccess, wp-config, localhost, testing, clone-site

My local setup for WordPress is at `http://127.0.0.3/blog`.

When calling `https://my.domain.name/blog/wp-login.php`, I get the page served; including Google CAPTCHA. But the login post to a `302` redirect to `http://127.0.0.3/blog`.

In order to overwrite my server default domain I added locally this to my `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://127.0.0.3/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://127.0.0.3/blog');
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN',false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN',false);
```

In my Fiddler Web Debugger script I am using the following code to redirect my browser to go to my local setup:

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("my.domain.name")){
    oSession.bypassGateway = true;
    if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT")){
        oSession["x-replywithtunnel"] = "FakeTunnel";
        return;
    }  
    oSession["x-overrideHost"] = "127.0.0.3";
    oSession.fullUrl = "http://127.0.0.3" + oSession.PathAndQuery;
}
```

How can I get WordPress returned page to be rewritten before it gets sent to the browser, so it changes all `127.0.0.3` to `my.domain.name`?

-- OR --

Is there a smarter way to go about all of this within WordPress?

I had a look at  [Change WordPress image URLs via filter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/332762/change-wordpress-image-urls-via-filter) because it is somewhat related, but could not figure it out.

Comment: Could you not tell WP its URL is my.domain.name then adjust your hosts file? WP doesn't need to know its IP is `127.0.0.3`

Comment: @TomJNowell I have a multi site setup and did not want to set a my.domain.name URL in wp-config.php.

Comment: you don't need to set the domain name in `wp-config.php`, I have multiple separate multisite installs running locally here, and WP is unaware of the IP it's serving from, and I don't set the URL in `wp-config.php`. I just set each site in a multisite to the desired domain and WP handles it fine. Settings the domain and site URLs in `wp-config.php` is unnecessary. The only thing I can forsee is that Fiddler doesn't know how to route the requests to WordPress but that's a Fiddler problem not a WP problem. TLDR: Just use real URLs in your WP installs

Comment: @TomJNowell I tried all kind of combinations, and nothing really worked the way I wanted it to work. By using Fiddler as described in my answer WordPress finally loads. And if I want to dump the live database onto the local database I can just copy it over, no need to do anything more to get it back up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to Fiddler's script in
%USER%\Documents\Fiddler2\Scripts\CustomRules.js under
`OnBeforeResponse` and the response rewrite started working

```
 static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
        if (m_Hide304s && oSession.responseCode == 304) {
            oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
        }
        if (oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type","text/html")){
            oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
            oSession.utilReplaceInResponse('127.0.0.3','my.domain.name');
            oSession.utilReplaceInResponse('http:','https:');
        }
    }
```

and needed to set

```
// define('WP_HOME','http://127.0.0.3/blog');
// define('WP_SITEURL','http://127.0.0.3/blog');
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN',false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN',false);
```

in wp-config.php

In order to be able to log in I also had to remove the plugin `simple-google-recaptcha`. There might be a way to set it up with reCAPTCHA not needing to be deactivated, but for now this is all I need.